# How to convert pre tag text into this in react js javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i was having a problem converting the current to example shown below. i tried to put in same line but it was ignoring spaces so i was stuck. how can i achieve this in java script or reactjs..

current pre tag

```
<pre>
    hello
        dan
</pre>
```

to this

```
<pre>
    hello    dan
        
</pre>
```

the idea is just replacing dan to upper sentence with same amount of spaces, help is appreciated, how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

`pre` tag has default `white-space: pre` parameter in CSS. It means that every space and every enter will be shown on a page. Here's the documentation how `white-space` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

I don't really understand your expectations, so you can try out each of this values: `white-space: normal | pre | nowrap | pre-wrap | -moz-pre-wrap | pre-line | inherit ;` and see how it goes.